# How to check if system reach the timeout?

Tags: linux, bash, timeout

I am running java jar file and psql command with bash script. I am using timeout command to stop any command if it runs for long time.

```
    TIMEOUT=2000
    timeout $TIMEOUT java -jar myApp.jar
    timeout $TIMEOUT java -jar myApp2.jar     
    timeout $TIMEOUT psql .....
```

I need to keep a flag for how many command are run out of time.

How could I check if timeout command is reach the limit and stops the command?

Answer (score 0):

For man timeout:

> If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.  If no signal is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The TERM signal kills any process that does not block or catch that signal.  It may be necessary to use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal cannot be caught, in which case the   exit status is 128+9 rather than 124.

You have to test for the value retur

```
timeout $TIMEOUT java -jar myApp.jar
CODE=$?
if [ $CODE -eq 124 ] || [ $CODE -eq 133] 
then
    echo "command xxx take more than $TIMEOUT to run"
fi
```

---

And with `bash`, you can create a function for that:

```
my_timeout () {
    TIMEOUT=$0
    shift
    timeout $TIMEOUT $*
    CODE=$?
    if [ $CODE -eq 124 ] || [ $CODE -eq 133] 
    then
        echo "command $* take more than $TIMEOUT to run"
    fi    
}


TIMEOUT=2000
my_timeout $TIMEOUT java -jar myApp.jar
my_timeout $TIMEOUT java -jar myApp2.jar
```

Comment: You'll need to check `timeout`'s specific exit status instead of "non-zero" -- what if the command itself returns non-zero? `timeout 5 sh -c 'echo hello world; exit 42'`

Comment: psql count select command return 1 when timeout but how could I know when the number of tuples are 1 or it timeout?